# Get node with the same name from multiple xmls together with their belonging filename, using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, csv, xpath, xml-parsing

I have many xml files that all contain the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<largersection>
    <sections>
        <section name="Section1Name">   
        </section>

        <section name="Section2Name">       
        </section>
    </sections>
</largersection>
```

with, of course, many more sections inside.

I need to have all the section names extracted to a separate file. I tried with powershell to extract them to a csv file. I managed to do that using the following:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\' -Filter '*.xml' |
  ForEach-Object {
      ([Xml](Get-Content -Path $_.FullName)).erpConnector.sections.section
  } |
  Select Name |
  Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\AllData.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

The output contains all the section names in one column, and it is already useful. However, it would achieve its full goal only if it would also output the belonging file of each section. I found information about object FullName and BaseName, but I am really a beginner in powershell and also xml, this is actually my first attempt at a script, mostly copying examples found online.

The output should be:

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>SectionName</th>
    <th>FileName</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Section1</td>
    <td>xml_number_one</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Section2</td>
    <td>xml_number_one</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>differentSectionName</td>
    <td>xml_number_two</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Please, let me know if it is possible and how to get the filename or path (complete) to show to which file a section belongs.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, I'd suggest use `Select-Xml` - when piping a file object to it, it'll attach the file path to the result! We just need to change your `Select Name` command slightly to get the output you need:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\ -Filter *.xml |
  Select-Xml -XPath '//sections/section[@Name]' |
  Select @{Name='Name';Expression={$_.Node.name}},Path |
  Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\AllData.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```